# jQuery not method for opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am not able to see the opacity in IE8 browser.
I think its because of the `not` method in jQuery....
Can you tell me how to fix it?
Providing my code below:

```
function soccerMatches(matches) {
    var $cricket = $('.color'),
        matchesIds = [],
        $soccers;

    $.each(matches, function(i, match) {
        matchesIds.push('#cricket' + match.title);
    });

    $soccers = $(matchesIds.join(', '));

    $cricket.not($soccers).addClass("testing1");
    $soccers.css('opacity', 1);

}

.testing1 {

    opacity: 0.33;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=33)";

}
```

Comment: well you are not setting the ms filter...

Comment: Are you having trouble with the opacity on $soccers? that variable appears to be a string, not a DOM element. Do you have some sample data top show what this works on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.testing1 {
    -moz-opacity: 0.33;
    opacity:.33;
    filter: alpha(opacity=33);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=33);
}
```

but you need to know that IE doesn't apply several styles to elements that don't have layout.

For more information : http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html